# Proving that $A'(x) = f(x)$

Tags: calculus

So imagine a curve $f$ that is continuous in the interval $[a,b]$. I now define the areal function $A(x)$ as the area under the curve from $a$ to $x$.

I also define $A(x + dx)$ as the area under the curve from $a$ to $x+dx$. I can now find the area under the curve from $x$ to $x + dx$ by: $A(x+dx) - A(x)$.

However, I'm already aware of two rectangles, and the area $A(x+dx) - A(x)$ is between these two rectangles' areas. They are:

1) $f(x)  dx$    ($f(x)$ is the height, $dx$ is the width)

and

2) $f(x+dx) dx$     ($f(x)$ is the height, $dx$ is the width)
* 
So, I can put it like this:

$$f(x) * dx   < A(x+dx) - A(x) < f(x+dx) dx$$

and if I divide by $dx$....

$$f(x)    < \frac{A(x+dx) - A(x)  }{  dx }< f(x+dx)$$

.... now I want to prove that when I take the limit of $\frac{A(x+dx) - A(x)  }{  dx}$ as $dx$ approaches $0$... that this is $f(x)$. Now, this happens by taking the same limit on ALL three sides, and thus the derivative of $\frac{A(x+dx) - A(x)  }{  dx }$ gets squeezed in between $f(x)$ and $f(x)$, thus becoming $f(x)$.....

Is the above correct, when trying to prove the fundamental theorem of calculus/ that $A'(x) = f(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

In principle your proof is correct.
There is only one point to note, you have assumed that $f(x)$ is increasing in $x$. As derivatives and continuity is a local property, there is no problem to assume that $f(x)$ is monotone on a interval around $x$.

I'd use $h$, instead of $dx$ on your proof. $dx$ has another meaning that could create confusion.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Hold on, $f$ needn't be differentiable, so there needn't be *any* interval on which it is monotone.